# What is the Google Calendar syntax for making appointments?

Tags: google-calendar

When an appointment is made in Google calendar, you can use "17:00 Name" to set the appointment time to 17 o'clock.

Now, is there other syntax that can be used? E.g. to set the location, repititions, ...? (Of course, without opening the settings)

Or even better, is a guide available somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

you can use "at" or "in" to specify a location

> meeting 9-1030am at Bob's office

the word "repeat" can also be used

> 9-10:30am repeat every Tuesday Meeting in Bob's office

the order doesn't seem to matter

> 9-10:30am Meeting in Bob's office repeat every Tuesday